# Access SQL Conditional Query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to retrieve data based on the contents of one column.

sample table

```
  Description    EID        Basecode        
   -----------    ----       ---------    
  ssdad          1001       S2378797     
  gfd            1002       S1164478     
  gfdsffsdf      1003       R1165778     
  ssdad          1004       M0007867     
  gfd            1005       N7765111     
  gfdsffsdf      1006       W5464111     
  gfd            1005       N7765111     
  gfdsffsdf      1006       A4000011 
  gfdsffsdf      1006       W5464111     
  ssdad          1001       2378797     
  gfd            1002       1164478  
  ssdad          1001       965000
  gfd            1002       780000
  yjgk           4456       540000
  kjhkh          2009       150000
  ddd            1004       1040
  d88jg          1004       14C676
   fsa           6565       158 
   fdh           1004       2Khlm
   ggdg          2009       967
```

If column data starts with letters then I want results from qr1; if it contains numbers starts with **96**, **78** ,**54** and length >6 then i get qry2 results.

How to retrieve data other than sorted in qry1 ,qry2?

How can I conditionally execute this in MS-Access?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do IIF statements that look like this basically...

```
ColValue: IIf((Len([col1])>6 And (Left([col1],2)="12" Or Left([col1],2)="13")),1,0)

ColValue: IIf(Left([col1],1) In ("a","b","c"),1,0)
```

(Note: add all the way to z)

Then if they meet your criteria, it is a 1 otherwise it is a 0.

Answer (score 0):

What if it does not satisfy any of the two conditions? I will return NULL, but you change it to what you want:

```
SELECT IIF((LEN([col1])>6 AND (LEFT([col1], 2) = "12" OR LEFT([col1], 2)="13")), qry2,
       IIF(ASC(UCASE(LEFT([col1], 1))) BETWEEN 65 AND 90, qry1, NULL))
FROM myTable
```